# Looping to a specific index within a string

Tags: javascript

I'm currently doing a puzzle and am having trouble formulating my thoughts on how to do the following. Heres some code for some context on my thoughts (this isn't working yet)

```
const words = ['this', 'is', 'my', 'dog', 'bit', 'bite', 'every']; 
const strings = ['thisis', 'thisisacat', 'thisisaduck', 'thisismy', 'thisismydog', 'bitevery']; 
var count;
for (var i = 0 ; i < strings.length ; i++)
{
    for (var j = 0; j <words.length; j++)
  {
    if(strings[i].indexOf(words[j]) !== -1)
    {
        count+=words[j].length;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically I want to first go to the word `this` check if it is in `strings[j]`. If it is then get the length of `words[i]`, and go to the `words[i]'th` position inside `strings[j]` meaning I want the '`is`' part of the '`thisis`'. Basically I just want to test whether each element in `strings` can be represented by any amount of combos in `words`. This of course can be done with regular expressions, but I would like to use the current thought process that I have.

**TLDR**

With my current way, how can I check whether words in the `words` array exist within each element of `strings`(I am attempting this with `indexOf`), and if it is, go to the length of that words position meaning go to the position where `i` is in `thisis`. I realize that the way I am phrasing it it might be a bit verbose, but I'm not sure how else to phrase it. Any help is appreciated.

**Example Run**

We are at `strings[i]`, now we check if any element in `words` is in `strings[i]`. Now `this` is in `'thisis'`, so add an index of four, since this has a length of four, to get to the 4th position and beyond of `thisis`, now we have `is`so loop again through the rest of `words`, now `is` is inside `is`, that means we have succesfully created a word from using some amount of words in the `words` array. Note, I actually don't  want to delete the `this` from `thisis`, as I know modifying strings altogether is very costly in memory.

**Another Run**

Take `thisismydog` in `strings`. Let us iterate through words. `this` is inside `thisismydog`, so now go to the 4th onwards of `thisismydog` ( since `this` has a length of 4) namely now we consider `ismydog`. Now iterate again looking at the elements in words. We see `is` is there, so we go to the second element in `ismydog`, namely `mydog`. Since we reach the end of the word we can successfully conclude that `thisismydog` can indeed be represented by a combination of those elements within words.

Comment: Describe the exact output you're trying to generate, preferably with 2 examples.

Comment: With your current way? And what if there's a better and simpler way?..

Comment: I've added an example, I'll add another one

Comment: Oh there surely is a simpler way, but I'm wondering if I can do it with the mindset i've approached it with.

Comment: The thing is, is I want to iterate within the string characters of each element to be incremented upon one. I added another example run

Comment: `var count = 0;`. Fix it, else it'll be `NaN`.

Comment: Answered ! Done !: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38677085/747579

Comment: Did his answer disseapear?